# Let $\mu$ be the lebesgue measure and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. When is true that $\mu (f(A)) \leq \mu (A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be the lebesgue measure. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. I want to know the minimum conditions for when is true that $\mu (f(A)) \leq \mu (A)$. I began recently with measure study and i don´t know if there exist some theorem about this neither its conditions. Apparently yes, but what is its proof? If someone can give me a hand I would be very grateful.
The special case I'm working with is taking compact $A$ and $f$ is $C^1$ with $m>n$.

Comment: as a technical note, you should specify $\mu_n, \mu_m$ for the different measure spaces since $\mu_m(A)=0$ when $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n<m$

Comment: @guy3141: That is fairly clear from context.

Comment: My earlier comment was incorrect. For example, $n=1,m=1$. Let $f(x) = \alpha x_1$ and $A$ be the $x_1$ axis. Then $\mu A = 0$ but $\mu f(A) = \infty $ for any $\alpha \neq 0$.

Comment: $m>n$? Won't the measure of the image always be $0$?

Comment: @Drek in "most cases" yes but it depends on the regularity of $f$, there are [filling space curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), by example curves from $\mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb{R} ^2$ that fill an open subset of the plane

Comment: @Masacroso Ah, right! I wonder then if my claim is always true when $A$ is connected or with some other similar hypothesis. I suppose I'm just finding my way back to a version of OP's original question though.

Comment: This is true if $f$ is Lipschitz with constant one (with respect to the $\ell^\infty$ norm), and $m \geq n$.